# Azure Storage Queue max value for MaxDequeueCount

Tags: azure, azure-storage-queues

Could anyone answer me how many retry attempts can Azure execute on a Queue message?
If I set MaxDequeueCount = Int32.MaxValue, will Azure really trigger any binded to this queue function 2147483647 times?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you set the MaxDequeueCount to Int32.MaxValue your message will retry for 2147483647 times, or until it succeeds. If even after these 2147483647 tries the message does not succeed, the message will be moved to the poison queue instead.

However, to prevent congestion from malformed/ overall incorrect messages, I would advise you to use a lower limit. Often messages fail due to user code, or incorrectly formatted payloads, which do not just fix them self in these retries, but require a user to interact with the payload object or the code instead.

Source [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#host-json)